# How can I ajax only html table rows instead of sending the entire form inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have tried  to ajax  using  post  to  jsp  script my  html table rows for weeks now with no success.Can anyone please  guide me on this?Below is  what I have done so far.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

            var form = document.getElementById("updateDealPmtForm");

            document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {


                $('#notSoCoolGrid > tr').each(function(event) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    var postData = {
                        paymentId:$('#paymentId').text(),
                        id:$('#deald').text(),
                        pType:$('#pType').text(),
                        pAmt:$('#pAmt').text(),
                        currency:$('#currency').text(),
                        pInvDate:$('#pInvDate').text(),
                        pRecDate:$('#pRecDate').text(),
                        comments:$('#comments').text()
                    };
                    console.log(postData);
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        url: "/update_deal_pmt_script.jsp",
                        data: postData.$('input, select').serialize() ,
                        success: function(msg){
                            alert("submitted");
                        }

                    });
                });


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, you want to transmit the content of your rows, each in the form showed in your current `postData`.

So this can be made *at once* for all rows (instead of ajaxing successively each of them).
It might be something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("updateDealPmtForm");
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var postData = [];
        $('#notSoCoolGrid > tr').each(function(event) {
            postData.push(
                paymentId:$('#paymentId').text(),
                id:$('#deald').text(),
                pType:$('#pType').text(),
                pAmt:$('#pAmt').text(),
                currency:$('#currency').text(),
                pInvDate:$('#pInvDate').text(),
                pRecDate:$('#pRecDate').text(),
                comments:$('#comments').text()
            );
        });
        console.log(postData);
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/update_deal_pmt_script.jsp",
            data: postData,
            success: function(msg){
                alert("submitted");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that I choosed (the simplest way, IMO) to make a simple array of rows, where each one is an object like you already structured them.

Last point: I notice you specified `async: false`.
I don't know why you did that, and so I kept it unchanged.
But note that it's not recommended, and is being on the road to become deprecated.

Comment: Thank  you  cFreed for your  quick response.I  just tried seems  push function can not  accept  the arguments you are trying to pass.I am  getting   syntax error.

Comment: I  was finally get  to remove syntax errors but  nothing is  submitted on the server:-

Comment: @Danny So you must test progressively: 1) check the output of `console.log(postData);`: is it's content like expected?; 2) if ok, look at the `/update_deal_pmt_script.jsp` page load (with something like Firebug): do you see the `postData` transmitted?; 3) if yes, it's an internal issue of the `/update_deal_pmt_script.jsp` script.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able  to solve  this issue,for that I want to post my answer it might be helpful for someone out there.My previous code was submitting a form before even  ajax call being triggered and I have to use Classes instead of IDs to identify my rows.I had to change the code completely to be able to submit the form

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#notSoCoolGrid tr').each(function(i, tr) {

                var postData = {
                    paymentId : $('.paymentId', tr).val(),
                    id : $('.deald', tr).val(),
                    pType:$('.pType', tr).val(),
                    pAmt:$('.pAmt',tr).val(),
                    currency:$('.currency',tr).val(),
                    pInvDate:$('.pInvDate',tr).val(),
                    pRecDate:$('.pRecDate',tr).val(),
                    comments:$('.comments',tr).val()
                }



                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/update_deal_pmt_script.jsp",
                    data: postData
                })
                        .done(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .fail(function(x, status, error) {
                            alert("Error: " + error);
                        });
            });
        });
```